# Por que se agregan "anclas" al final de la URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una pagina web  que funciona con pestañas y subpestañas. Cuando en una sunpestaña agrego informacion al refrescar hago un `.click()` sobre la misma pestaña (JavaScript) y se agrega un # al final de la URL. El problema es que a veces se agregan nombres de las pestañas de la url y empiezan a fallar los js de las pestañas.

Hay un motivo por el cual se agrega esto a la URL, y existe alguna forma de quitarlos?
Gracias

Comment: Si no quieres que el click cambie el hash de la URL, en vez de darles atributo `href="#"` dales atributo `hrer="javascript:void(0)"`

Comment: Muchas Gracias :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como puse en mi comentario, es frecuente que al usar links como botones (algo común en material design o bootstrap) el elemento tiene la forma:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" id="alerta" >Alerta!</a>
```

Y un handler del tipo

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#alerta', function () {
            var msg = 'Usted pinchó alerta';
            console.log(msg);
});
```

Al pinchar en un link disfrazado de botón como ese, estás además llamando al link `#` que se interpreta como una ruta relativa a la actual, i.e. se añade a la url.

Esto sirve por ejemplo para navegar a un anchor o al ID de un elemento contenido en el documento (así puedes hacer un link a una sección específica de una página larga).

Cuando usas alguna clase de router ([Backbone.Router](http://backbonejs.org/#Router), [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/)) ese hash en la URL no es inofensivo. La ruta está asociada a acciones dentro de una Single Page App (SPA). Por ejemplo:

- http://dominio/#/tab1 muestra la página en el primer tab
- http://dominio/#/tab2 muestra la página en el segundo tab

Al pinchar en un link apuntando a `#` te llevará a

```
http://dominio/#
```

Que no cumple con ningún patrón esperado por el router.

Si no quieres que el click cambie el hash de la URL, en vez de darles atributo `href="#"` dales atributo `href="javascript:void(0)"`

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-warning" id="alerta" >Alerta!</a>
```

**¿Qué ocurre exactamente al usar `javascript:void(0)`?**

Empezar la url con `javascript:` es un prefijo válido para un [URI Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier), tal como es empezar la url con `http://`, `https://` o `magnet:`. En vez de interpretarse como un link de navegación, se interpreta como la ejecución de un script. En este caso, la ejecución de `void(0)`.

El operador [void](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) siempre retorna `undefined`, por lo que el browser evalúa el link a `undefined` y se queda donde mismo.

Answer (score 1):

Esa notación se usa generalmente para redirigir a elemento con un id específico por ejemplo:

```
<div id="contenido">
    Contenido
</div>
```

Puedes tener un enlace que te lleve ahí:

```
<a href="#contenido">Ir al contenido</a>
```

O hasta puedes ir a otra página:

```
<a href="mipagina.html#contenido">Ir al contenido</a>
```

En tu caso parace que se pone para seleccionar la tab en la cual se ha hecho click.

Saludos